# Why GNOME3 apps close such long?

Tags: gnome, performance, gtk

For example system monitor and calculator. It takes about 1 second after clicking close for app to vanish from my screen. Why it is so long. Or it is only my personal bug? PS using Xubuntu 14.04; some of gtk3 apps close instantly (Evince, disks etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch, that actually the *applications* are stopped roughly around the same time, however the *windows* itself are destroyed at a different time. These are minor programming issues - if this is the case.